How to evaluate $\int_0^\infty \tanh\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\right) \, dx $

Question

How to evaluate
$$\int_0^\infty \tanh\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\right) \, dx
$$

My attempt

$$
I(y) = \int_0^\infty \tanh\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\right) \, dx
$$
Now, when transforming $I(y)$ into a double integral using the Laplace transform:
$$
I(y) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} \left(1 - \cos(ys)\right) \tanh\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) \, ds \, dx
$$
Next, we simplify the integrand by performing the inner integral with respect to $x$:
$$
I(y) = \int_0^\infty (1 - \cos(ys)) \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} \tanh\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) \, dx \, ds
`$$
Denote the inner integral as $v$, which is given by:
$$
v = \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} \frac{1 - e^{-\pi x}}{1 + e^{-\pi x}} \, dx
$$
This integral can be expressed as an infinite sum:
$$
v = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \int_0^\infty e^{-(s+k\pi)x} (1 - e^{-\pi x}) \, dx
$$
$$= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \left( \frac{1}{s + k\pi} - \frac{1}{s + (k+1)\pi} \right)
= \frac{1}{s} - 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{s + (k+1)\pi}$$
I don't know how to evaluate the last sum and $\int_0^\infty (1 - \cos(ys)) \, ds$. Note that I don't know the closed form for $y= 1, 2, 3, \dots$.

$y$ is a constant right?

@Sahaj No,I've made the corrections; please review the edited version.

I believe for even $y$, $I=2H_y - H_{\frac{y}2}$. I’ll try to work something out for odd $y$ as well.

For odd $y$, $I = H_{\frac{y-1}2} + \ln(4)$.

I used complex analysis to find these results. If OP wishes, I can upload a sketch of proof. However, I do not know Fourier transform so it will not match your attempt.

@Sahaj Of course, I have knowledge of complex analysis. Even if I didn't, you should post your solution because it will ultimately be helpful to the community.

I like your questions

Let's consider
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty \tanh\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) \left(\frac{x}{x^2 + a^2}- \frac{x}{x^2 + b^2}\right) \, dx$$
then the initial integral $\,\displaystyle I_0=I(a=0, b=y)$. Integrating by parts
$$I(a,b)=-\frac\pi8\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln\frac{a^2+x^2}{b^2+x^2}}{\cosh^2\frac{\pi x}2}dx=J(b)-J(a)$$
where
$$ J(a)=\frac\pi8\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln(x^2+a^2)}{\cosh^2\frac{\pi x}2}dx=\frac{\pi \ln2}2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{\cosh^2\pi x}+\frac\pi2\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln(\frac a2-ix)}{\cosh^2\pi x}dx$$
Using the property $\displaystyle \,\ln\big(\frac a2-ix\big)=\ln\Gamma\big(\frac a2-i(x+i)\big)-\ln\Gamma\big(\frac a2-ix\big)$ and $\displaystyle \cosh^2\big(\pi(x+i)\big)=\cosh^2\pi x$ we can present the last integral as a complex integral along the rectangular contour $\,C\,:\,-R\to R\to i+R\to -i+R\to -R, \,\big(R\to\infty\big)$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln(\frac a2-ix)}{\cosh^2\pi x}dx=-\oint_C\frac{\ln\Gamma(\frac a2-iz)}{\cosh^2\pi z}dz$$
We have one double-pole inside the contour at $z=\frac i2$; therefore,
$$J(a)=\pi\ln2-\frac\pi2\Re\,2\pi i\underset{z=\frac i2}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\ln\Gamma(\frac a2-iz)}{\cosh^2\pi z}=\frac\pi 2+\Psi\big(\frac12+\frac a2\big)$$
$$I(a,b)=\Psi\big(\frac12+\frac b2\big)-\Psi\big(\frac12+\frac a2\big)$$
and the initial integral
$$I_0=-\Psi\big(\frac12\big)+\Psi\big(\frac12+\frac y2\big)$$

I also worked out a solution along similar lines but this is nice, espcially for the generalization with the extra parameter $b$.

Nice solution as always

$$\Omega=\int_0^{\infty} \tanh \left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{y^2+x^2}\right) d x$$
Using : $$\tanh \left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)=\frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(2 n+1)^2+x^2}$$
\begin{align*}\Omega &=\frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(2 n+1)^2+x^2}-\frac{x^2}{\left(y^2+x^2\right)\left((2 n+1)^2+x^2\right)}\right) d x \\
\Omega&=2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2 n+1}-\frac{1}{2 n+1+y}\right)=\psi\left(\frac{1+y}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \end{align*}

Concerning the last summation, since
$$s + (k+1)\pi= \pi \left(k+\frac{s+\pi }{\pi }\right)$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{s + (k+1)\pi}=\frac 1{2\pi}\left(\psi \left(\frac{s+2 \pi }{2 \pi }\right)-\psi\left(\frac{s+\pi }{2
   \pi }\right)\right)=\frac 1{2\pi}\left(H_{\frac{s}{2 \pi }}-H_{\frac{s-\pi }{2 \pi }}\right)$$
